# does git add only add untracked files or modified files to the staging area?

Tags: git

I'm new to Git, let's say I create 10 files in once, then I added those 10 files to stage area, then committed them.

And then I created another file(11th file), because this file's name is very long, I don't want to type git command like

> git add lllllllllllllongname.txt

instead, I typed:

> git add .

Does git also re-add those 10 files created on the first time to the staging area again internally?
becuase I checked Git docs, it doesn't say `add` command will only add untracked files or modified files to the staging area?

Comment: Have you tried it? I highly recommend it. You can always clear the staging area with git reset if things don't go as planned.

Comment: And no, it won't add any files it doesn't think have been modified.

Comment: "Re-adding" the same file makes no difference. Every commit is a complete snapshot of the repository. Effectively, all tracked files are already staged with their current contents.

Comment: In addition you can always run `git status` to see what git sees as modified

Comment: It does not add files. It adds modifications. A new file is a modification. If you modify a file, you need git add to add those modifications.
Read this entirely: https://git-scm.com/docs
It's short and you won't need to ask things on git add anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing here is that **the staging area already contains all your files**.

If your repository is not too large, try running:

```
git ls-files --stage
```

If your repository has lots of files, this produces a huge amount of output.  It's still all just a case of *looking* so it's OK, but you'll probably want to pipe the output through a pager—`git ls-files` is not an everyday usage Git command so it is not self-paging the way, e.g., `git log` and `git diff` are.

You will see that even on a fresh checkout, when `git status` says:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

your staging area contains lots of files!  The important thing is that what's in the staging area right now is *the same as* what's in each of the other two areas.

Remember, Git has, at all, times, *three* copies of each tracked file.  Suppose one of your tracked files is named `README.md`.  It's there in your work-tree, where you can see it and work on it.  But there are *three copies of it!*

- There's `HEAD:README.md`, which is the frozen, committed file in the current commit.  Use `git show HEAD:README.md` to see it.
- Then there is the `README.md` in your staging area.  Use `git show :README.md` to see it.  This copy of the file is in the frozen *format*, just like the one in your current commit, but unlike the one in your current commit, you can change it, by replacing it wholesale with the one from your work-tree.
- Last, there's `README.md`, which you can see and work with.  You don't need any special command to show it because it's just an ordinary file.

When you run `git commit`, Git will take *whatever is in the staging area copy of the file* and freeze it into the *new* commit you make.  So if you've changed the *work-tree* copy of `README.md`, but have not touched the *staging* copy, your next `git commit` will use the old, unchanged staging copy.  If you want it to use the new one, you run `git add` to copy *from* the work-tree, *to* the staging-area.  This compresses the updated `README.md` down into the frozen format, ready to be committed.  It's not actually committed yet, it's just ready.

If you re-add files that have not changed, Git will see that the updated frozen-format file is still the same as the original frozen-format file, already in the `HEAD` commit and already in the staging area.  It won't matter whether or not you copied the not-updated file into a not-updated, still-the-same, still-ready-to-go file in the staging area.

In effect, the staging area is your *proposed next commit*.  It starts out matching your *current commit*.  If you re-add files, that's harmless: either they're *unchanged*, so they still match your current commit, or they're changed but you wanted them to be changed in your proposed next commit anyway.

The only time you *don't* want to `git add` some particular file is when it is changed in your work-tree, but you want:

- to leave it *not*-changed in the staging area, or
- to leave it, or take it, *out* of the staging area entirely, so that it will be absent from your next commit.

If file `README.md` is in your *current* commit, and you take it *out* of the staging area, so that it's not in your *next* commit, then you have—in Git's view of things anyway—simply deleted `README.md`.  It doesn't matter whether or not you've deleted `README.md` in your *work-tree*.  The work-tree isn't for *Git*, it's for *you*.  The work-tree is where you can see and work with your files.  Git uses the staging-area copy to make the *next* commit, and the committed copies—there is one in *every* commit—for the committed copies.

Answer (score 0):

When using `git add .`, git **only** adds files to the staging area that have changes.

If a new file is edited or added after the initial staging, then **only** those changes will be added on the next stage.  Committing makes no difference in this regard, but it makes unstaging more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

`If you create 10 files first (1.txt,2.txt...…,10.txt) then commit all as below`

```
git add .
git commit "commit message"
git status
```

If you execute `git status` then its visible to you there is nothing to commit.

Then when you create next file i.e 11.txt, now if you execute `git status` then you will see only one file that you have recently created, so again follow above 3 command then you realize that only one file is added for commit i.e 11.txt

```
git add . 
git status
git commit "commit message"
git status
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`git add` documentation for *pathspec*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt-ltpathspecgt82308203) describes git’s behavior when adding directories.

> **`git add`**`[options…] [<pathspec>…]`
>
> **<pathspec>…**​
>
> … Also a leading directory name (e.g. `dir` to add `dir/file1` and `dir/file2`) can be given to update the index to match the current state of the directory as a whole (e.g. specifying `dir` will record not just a file `dir/file1` modified in the working tree, a file `dir/file2` added to the working tree, but also a file `dir/file3` removed from the working tree). Note that older versions of Git used to ignore removed files; use `--no-all` [or `--ignore-removal`] option if you want to add modified or new files but ignore removed ones.

In your case and assuming a recent version of git, `git add .` will stage changes in your current directory subtree that are any of

- New files
- Modified files
- Deleted files

For the changes you have already staged, those files do not appear modified because the content in your work tree will be the same as the content in the index or staging area.

---

The change to stage removed files by default arrived with [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt#L32-L36).

> `git add <path>` is the same as `git add -A <path>` now, so that
>   `git add dir/` will notice paths you removed from the directory and
>   record the removal.  In older versions of Git, `git add <path>` used
>   to ignore removals.  You can say `git add --ignore-removal <path>` to
>   add only added or modified paths in *path*, if you really want to.